# Best way to fix divs on top of image section

Tags: css

I am trying to achieve the following effect:

- Have an image of a map fill up the entire width of the browser.
- Have divs that are shaped as circles and are located on certain sections of the image
- Have the divs continue to be located on the correct place of the map independent of browser size.

My background image is set to cover my screen with the following css:

```
#map {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: url('http://imgur.com/iqR0WZN.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

And the divs that sit on top of the image have the following css:

```
.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;  
}

#dot1{
  position:absolute;
  top: 35%;
  left: 62%;
  background: red;
}

#dot2{
  position:absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 25%;
  background: red;
}
```

The Html that defines these elements:

```
<div id=map>
 <div id="dot1" class="circle"></div>
    <div id="dot2" class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle to demonstrate what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/fCrK6/

Note: the circles are dynamic -- their color and size change constantly depending on an api call that serves me that information. This is why they should not simply be fixed on the background image itself. I have javascript running these changes.

How do I make it so that those dots are ALWAYS on the same spot in relation to the image, and not the browser size? Ideally I want each circle to be on top of Lands End Stage and Twin Peak Stage indicated in the map image.

I have tried to solve this issue with a bunch of media queries, but it's A LOT of media queries and doesn't seem like the best solution.

Comment: Please create a working http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: @JaredFarrish http://jsfiddle.net/fCrK6/

Comment: How about just editing the image?  Is there a particular reason why this needs to be done in HTML/CSS?  If it is a fixed visual, then go for a graphics solution.

Comment: P.S. I do not do graphics (at all), but this took just a second: http://i61.tinypic.com/2sbtmhh.png.  And, I did not use Gimp or Photoshop.  I just used Paint.

Comment: the circles are dynamic -- their color and size change constantly depending on an api call that serves me that information @DRD

Comment: That could be done with a responsive image map. https://github.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/xue4j/.  Note, this implementation was done, first and foremost, as a proof of concept.  How you adopt it to your application is totally up to you.

P.S. Interesting question.

HTML:

```
<div id = "map">
    <img src = "http://imgur.com/iqR0WZN.png" />
    <div class = "screen"></div>
</div>
```

Styles:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body, #map {
    height: 100%;
}

#map {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

#map > .screen,
#map > img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

#map > .screen:before, 
#map > .screen:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 2.5vmax;
    height: 2.5vmax;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    top: 52%;
    left: 26%;
}

#map > .screen:after {
    left: auto;
    top: 38%;
    right: 27%;
}

@media screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 2842/2383) {
    #map > img {
        width: 100vw;
    }

    #map > .screen {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 83.85vw;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-aspect-ratio: 2842/2383) {
    #map > img {
        height: 100vh;
    }

    #map > .screen {
        height: 100vh;
        width: 119.26vh;
}
```

Comment: I like your solution, and it works. 

But how could assign specific ids (#circle1) to each circle with your solution?

I am using the d3.js library to create my circles with a glowing effect, and being able to reference them by ID is important.

Comment: That's basic stuff.  Just replace `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements with markup: http://jsfiddle.net/L4pSJ/.